# how can i implement a water bottle getting filled on android?

Tags: android

I want to make an app where you can add how many ounces of water you drink a day and an animation of a water bottle filling up shows up. How would I be able to approach this?

Comment: You can simply use an **underlayed** ImageView which height grows depending on a percentage... which seems to me something very close to a ProgressBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-use **GIF** image from designer and use library to show it.

for example : [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

2-use images that show by **animation timer**.

Comment: would this approach still work if i only want to fill the water bottle little by little until it is full completely ?

Answer (score 7):

You can make it easily using frame animation.

[image: Glass filling]

Create an animation list. Like this

```
 filling_animation.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:oneshot="true">

        <item
            android:duration="50"
            android:drawable="@drawable/glass1"/>

        <item
            android:duration="50"
            android:drawable="@drawable/glass2"/>

        <item
            android:duration="50"
            android:drawable="@drawable/glass3"/>

        <item
            android:duration="50"
            android:drawable="@drawable/glass4"/>


    </animation-list>
```

Then add the ImageView in your layout using the background of animationlist.

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_glass1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/filling_animation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/image_view_glass2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Then in your activity onClick of something or onstart call this

```
((AnimationDrawable) mGlassView1startkground()).start();
```

You can even set the animationlistfilling.xml as the background of the imageview programmatically and then call the animation.